# MYSQL error don't know how to solve this

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to get the first data of my table. i want to display the Amountpaid, and Sum(Amountpaid) at the same time.

when i use this code the amountpaid always get null but the SUM(Amountpaid) will show its value

```
SELECT Amountpaid, Sum(Amountpaid) as total FROM mofficetbl Order by Number Limit 1;
```

but when i use this:

```
Select Amountpaid from mofficetbl Order by Number LIMIT 1;
```

the Amoutpaid will show.

i want to get the 2 columns at the same time. 
Need help

Comment: MrTux- If you're going to edit a [post, at least ensure you do it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@EJP is correct. *SUM* with *Order By* does not make any sense.

And if I understand the problem you really want the SQL Query

```
select Amountpaid, (select sum(Amountpaid) from mofficetbl) as total from mofficetbl order by Number limit 1;
```

Comment: it is possible to run the SUM & order by together, see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f1e0/1/0

Comment: Yeah @Lupin its working there but I am not sure why this not works with PostgreSql. And Here I mean of doing SUM with Order By clause where The SUM function will add up all rows, so the order by clause is useless.

Comment: @Lupin have you tired executing query **SELECT price, sum(price) as sum_this FROM test_sum;** this works too like charm ;)

Comment: My bad, i was wrong as i did not check that the query really orders the results. @MaNKuR and EJP were correct